# MVC custom routing setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. I've got my default routing setup as :

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Demo.Controllers" }
        );
```

That works beautifully.

I'd like to setup the routing to also accommodate the following path :

***Apps***/***DemoApp1*** ">>controllers>>models>>views under Demo1"

So that I'd be able to add a folder called ***DemoApp2*** under Apps and still have it work the same. The folder Apps must act like an Area if that makes sense.

Comment: If you would like it to act like an Area, why don't you use an Area?

Comment: @ColinBacon excellent comment. Exactly what I was thinking. Ryan, I would consider adding better details to the question, like how does the url look now, and how do you want the url to look like after, and do you want both urls to work. I read your question couple of times but couldn't really understand, and seeing you had no comments nor answers I think others didn't understand as well

Comment: Thanks I found a solution from MVC developers who funny enough understood me perfectly :) cheers